# Google Actions - not verified user on Apple devices

Tags: action, actions-on-google

I have a problem testing my Google Action. Precisely it tells me that I am not a verified user (so I cannot proceed since I need to do the account linking routine), only on Apple devices. I tried with the same Google account on a Samsung device and all went well.
Any ideas?
Thanks

EDIT
I wrote to Google support and they said there is an IOS bug but simply you can go to assistant app --> click on account settings --> Devices --> both for google home device and for the IOs device deactivate and activate Personal Results. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with iOS 14.6 update. I faced the same issue on latest iOS version but same action is working well on iOS 13.6